# WHERE statement inside if condition in SQL

Tags: php, sql

Can I do a WHERE clause inside an IF statement?

Like I want something like this:

```
     $SQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `row` DESC");
     $rows = mysql_fetch_array($SQL);
     $email = $_SESSION['email_of_user'];

        if($rows["row"] == "1" WHERE `row`='$email' : ?> (Pulls the logged in user's email)
        Edit Server
        <?php  else : ?>
        Add Server
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Do I need (" where the WHERE statement is? Because I tried that and it didn't seem to work...

Or can I do it with an if condition inside of a where clause? Not sure of all these terms yet so correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: `WHERE` would be SQL and not PHP syntax. And if you can show more information about `$row` (what is stored in it; how it's populated) there is probably a way to perform the task within PHP's nomenclature (if not within a SQL query itself).

Comment: Ok, added more information about rows but it pretty much just fetches the $SQL.

Comment: how can `row` be `1` _and_ `$email` (unless `$email=1`)?

Comment: @Brad Christie Email is loaded through sql using $_SESSION, so email = the email that is logged into the database. Updated question.

Comment: ok. So what column in `table` (in your example) should equal `1` then? I'm guessing it's not `row`. Would it be more like `$row['id'] = 1 && $row['email'] == $email`?

Comment: Sorry pal, but you better start with a php and mysql tut instead of posting here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix up **a query statement with PHP's statement**. Instead write a query extracting desired results and check if there are any rows from that query.

I will show you an example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE `field` = '1' && `email`='$email'"; //Create similar query
$result = mysqli_query($query, $link); //Query the server
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) { //Check if there are rows
    $authenticated = true; //if there is, set a boolean variable to denote the authentication
}

//Then do what you want
if($authenticated) {
     echo "Edit Server";
} else {
     echo "Add Server";
}
```

Since Aaron has shown such a effort to encourage safe code in my example. Here is how you can do this securely. PDO Library provides options to bind params to the query statement in the safe way. So, here is how to do it.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass); //Create the connection

//Create the Query Statemetn
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE field = :field AND email = :email');

//Binds Parameters in the safe way
$sth -> bindParam(':field', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth -> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STRING);

//Then Execute the statement
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(); //This returns the result set as an associative array
```

Comment: Yea I have a query and it grabs the table, but is there anyway that if the player who has that specific email has a 1 in a certain row doesn't get the add server and only the edit?

Comment: @user1907276, You can combine conditions like `\`field\` = '1' and \`email\` = '$email'`

Comment: Has been awhile since I've used PHP, but isn't there a different way to inject parameters without allowing SQL injection?  Even as beginner PHP programmer it seemed like something I was able to grasp easily.

Comment: @Starx Did that but it doesn't grab the row where the email is located. I understand now though that you can't do that, guess I will attempt to figure out another way to do it. Don't know how but I guess I will try.

Comment: @user1907276, Of course you can grab that row. Can you fully explain your need? Show your data structure and which row you want in that.

Comment: @Starx Someone could possible enter an email like `';Select * From Users;Drop Table Users;`.  Lots of variations like this and are a common way for websites to be compromised.  The techniques for preventing this are pretty simply and should become habit for anyone doing DB access in a web app.

Comment: @AaronLS, Yeah that is the truth, but are you suggesting that I should have escaped the parameters before I wrote that example?

Comment: @Starx Yes, something like mysql_real_escape_string if that is still the common practice in PHP. I don't think it makes the example significantly more complicated, and encourages it become habit.  If someone asks me how to pass parameters to a query, I wouldn't just append the strings together, even though that would indeed work, it is widely regarded as the wrong way to do it because no production application would ever have code like that unless it was absolutely necessary for a dynamic query. Haven't used PHP in so long though so rather than answer myself, I just suggest an improvement.

Comment: @AaronLS, I am glad for your suggestion but I thought it would be unnecessary for the above post. Anyways, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not sufficient to protect the attacks. Its always better to use PDO extension instead. Check it out, I have updated the answer.